# Print from continuous "infinite" roll in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I have the following piece of code:

```
var pdialog = new PrintDialog();

PageMediaSize size = new PageMediaSize(PageMediaSizeName.Unknown, number(_label.Settings.FullPaperWidth), number(_label.Settings.FullPaperHeight));

try
{
    pdialog.PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(), Properties.Settings.Default.PrinterName);
    pdialog.PrintQueue.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.PageMediaSize = size;
    pdialog.PrintQueue.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.PageMediaType = PageMediaType.Continuous;

    pdialog.PrintQueue.Commit();
    pdialog.PrintVisual(vis, "Label");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning, MessageBoxResult.OK);
  }


.....


private float number(float numb)
{
    return  numb/ 25.4F * 96; //(converting millimeter to 1/96 inches)
}
```

**Problem**

As you can see, I put the `PageMediaType` on `Continuous` since I will be printing on a continuous "infinitely long" roll, so I should be able to make infinitely long pages. However, the printer stops to print at the same height as `pdialog.PrintableAreaHeight` and then cuts off the roll. How can I print pages that are longer than the default `PrintableAreaHeight`?

**Edit**

I got it working!! I'm able to print for example 15cm pages now at once withouth cutting the paper even though that is much longer than the default PrintableAreaHeight, which is what's supposed to happen. I changed PageMediaSizeName to Roll06Inch which did the job... but I wonder what the difference is! Why does `Roll06Inch` or `Roll08Inch` or any  of them work but `Unknown` doesn't? Why does `Unknown` just cut it off? Doesn't make much sense to me! Hope someone can explain!

Comment: `System.Printing` is not WPF.

Comment: @Dai true, I included Winform as assembly references I think. I mean it works now except that I don't understand exactly why. How would I do this in a true WPF way? Only the PageMediaSize part is using system.printing